# how to efficiently strip a string with delimiting characters on both ends?

Tags: python

good day guys! suppose i have a string with a format like so ^a.b.c^ and i want to only get a.b.c . can you teach me a more efficient way to strip the delimiters than my code below? thanks

```
### line = '^123.456.102345^'
start = line.find ('^')
line = line[(start+1):]
end = line.find ('^')
line = line[:end]
print line
```

Comment: Are the characters you want to remove the first and last one in the string? Or can they be anywhere? And if so, can there be more than 2 of them? Please be more precise in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> s = '^a.b.c^'
>>> s.strip('^')
'a.b.c'
```

Check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for `str.strip`

Comment: @Geoffrey: `str.strip` only removes the leading and trailing characters.